# Object Positions Reset On Blender Load

Tags: transforms, customization, geometry, coordinates, groups

So I am attempting to make a modular environment in Blender, so I'm modeling many pieces in one scene to make sure they all match up properly before separating them out.

However, whenever I restart Blender after saving and closing it, many of my grouped objects (and their subobjects) have positions reset NOT to where I placed them.

For example, take a look at this:
[image: Incorrect positions]

Here you can see that the door pieces are in the "open" state, when I left them closed AND the "column" for the wall on the left has been moved from being flush with the wall (on the side) to being inside it.

It appears to be trying to move all of the objects to 0,0,0 which is what is messing this up. I'm not sure if it's an object hierarchy problem, but here is my hierarchy if anyone has ideas there:

Wall_Normal (parent)

- Wall_Normal_Column (child)

Empty Axis Object (parent)

- Door_Left (child a)
- Door_Right (child b)

Is there a reason why object positions (and their relative subobjects) aren't being saved?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a screenshot of the meshes, when they are placed at the locations where you want them? Also consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post the link in your question.

Comment: can that be related to the current timeline frame ?

Comment: Have you placed location keyframes anywhere on the timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lemon/atomicbezierslinger, they were exactly right!

I had a few animations placed on objects that I had decided not to use, yet had not deleted. The frame 1 keyframe of these animations was set to 0 - resulting in the effect described above.

Simply deleting the animations (since I am not using them) fixed the issue!

Comment: I can't accept it for 2 days, but I for sure will then!